# modifing request() array returns error Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have a form which includes input names with arrays, examples:

```
user_profile[birth_day]
user_profile[birth_month]
user_profile[birth_year]
user_profile[birthdate]
```

now i want to combine them and make a new request property.

i found a solution but i know it's bad practice:

```
$user_profile['birthdate'] = Carbon::parse(implode("-", [$request->user_profile['birth_day'], $request->user_profile['birth_month'], $request->user_profile['birth_year']]))->format('Y-m-d');
$request->request->add(['user_profile' => $user_profile+$request->user_profile]);
```

When i get `$request->user_profile['birthdate']` it returns the correct input, if filled in. But when i try to modify `$request->user_profile['birthdate']` when it is empty with:

```
$reuest->user_profile['birthdate'] = Carbon::parse(implode("-", [$request->user_profile['birth_day'], $request->user_profile['birth_month'], 
$request->user_profile['birth_year']]))->format('Y-m-d');
```

i get the following error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   Illuminate\Http\Request::$user_profile has no effect

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I guess this will work

$reuest->user_profile->birthdate = Carbon::parse(implode("-", [$request->user_profile['birth_day'], $request->user_profile['birth_month'], 
$request->user_profile['birth_year']]))->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: $request->user_profile->birthdate = 1; generates the following error: "ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::$user_profile has no effect"

Comment: okey, then you need to assign request data into new variable and u can access that in your process.